# How to have celery expire results when using a database backend

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I'm not sure I understand how `result_expires` works.

I read,

> result_expires
>
> Default: Expire after 1 day.
>
> Time (in seconds, or a timedelta object) for when after stored task tombstones will be deleted.
>
> A built-in periodic task will delete the results after this time (celery.backend_cleanup), assuming that celery beat is enabled. The task runs daily at 4am.
>
> ...
>
> When using the database backend, celery beat must be running for the results to be expired.

(from here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires)

So, in order for this to work, I have to actually do something like this:

`python -m celery -A myapp beat -l info --detach`

?

Is that what the documentation is referring to by "celery beat is enabled"? Or, rather than executing this manually, there is some configuration that needs to be set which would cause `celery beat` to be called automatically?

Comment: Please break down your posts into discrete questions--it makes it much harder to answer a six-part question than one that only has one or two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: celery beat--you are correct.  If you use a database backend, you have to run celery beat as you posted in your original post.  By default celery beat sets up a daily task that will delete older results from the results database.  If you are using a redis results backend, you do not have to run celery beat.  How you choose to run celery beat is up to you, personally, we do it via systemd.

If you want to configure the default expiration time to be something other than the default 1 day, you can use the [`result_expires`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires) setting in celery to set the number of seconds after a result is recorded that it should be deleted.  e.g., 1800 for 30 minutes.

Comment: However, if celery's scheduler will only hit at 04:00 am, then what point is there to set result_expires at something like 1800 (seconds)? Since the check will be performed at 04:00 am, the shortest time you can wait before cleaning up is 1 day.

Comment: Like I said, you asked seven questions in your original post.  You can't expect anyone to answer all of them.

Comment: Okay... and just to make sure... from what I understand, the results are also stored / cached in memory, right? Is there a risk that memory usage would be exploding if I have my celery processes running for months without interruption - or celery knows to drop the results from memory automatically?

Comment: You say "If you are using a Redis results backend, you do not have to run celery beat." Why is this? I cannot find anything in the documentation about Redis being different in terms of result expirations

Comment: Redis has expiration built into it -- you can set TTLs on any key.  When the TTL goes to 0, redis will delete the key for you.  The celery redis backend will set the TTL to the value of the `result_expires` setting.  So, we don't need any additional celery beat task to delete older results from the result backend when using redis because redis will delete them for us.